# how can i use json explict function ? to pull the data fom different sites

Tags: jquery, json, html, jquery-mobile

can i use json explicit function i,e{http://www.example.org/?json=get_recent_posts} to pull the data from other popular sites like Forbes etc..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Websites must provide the JSON for you to access, via some sort of built in webservice. There is no way to automatically convert HTML content to JSON in a meaningful way. You can search or request that a site provide a JSON webservice, or try to parse the HTML (or RSS if provided) yourself.